# Compute mean and standard deviation in 2-d matrix

Tags: matlab

```
    x  y
    1  1.2
    1  2.3 
    1  4.5
    2  2.3
    2  1.2
    2  0.8
```

Convert to :

```
 x   ymean     ystandard-deviation
 1    value       value
```

How can I can convert the first matrix to the second?

Comment: I don't follow what you actually want to compute.  Do you want to compute the mean and std. dev. of the `y` values?  It's not very clear what you want.

Comment: yes corresponding to each x value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use logical indexing to extract out the corresponding `y` values for each unique `x` value, then find the mean and standard deviation of the resulting `y` values.

Specifically:

```
x = [1 1 1 2 2 2];
y = [1.2 2.3 4.5 2.3 1.2 0.8];
y1 = y(x == 1);
y2 = y(x == 2);

m1 = mean(y1);
s1 = std(y1);
m2 = mean(y2);
s2 = std(y2);
```

We get:

```
>> m1

m1 =

    2.6667

>> m2

m2 =

    1.4333

>> s1

s1 =

    1.6803

>> s2

s2 =

    0.7767
```

`m1,m2` and `s1,s2` are the means and standard deviations of the `y` values corresponding to `x = 1` and `x = 2` respectively.

---

In general, you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to group all of the `y` values according to each unique `x` value.  This way, you can accommodate for as many unique values of `x` without having the need to use logical indexing for each unique value of `x`.

In the case where `x` is unsorted, we can **sort** them first using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) where we use the first output contains all of the unique `x` values and we use the third output that reassigns each value of `x` to be a unique ID that is sorted.  These would be used as keys into `accumarray`:

```
[vals, ~, id] = unique(x);
m = accumarray(id, y, [], @mean);
s = accumarray(id, y, [], @std);
```

`m` and `s` will contain the mean and standard deviation for each unique value of `x`.  Also, the corresponding positions of `m` and `s` correspond to the same positions in `vals`.

Let's say we had this example instead:

```
x = [1 2 3 2 4 2 1];
y = [1.2 2.3 4.5 2.3 1.2 0.8 1.6];
```

If we used the above code, we get:

```
>> vals

vals =

     1     2     3     4

>> m

m =

    1.4000
    1.8000
    4.5000
    1.2000

>> s

s =

    0.2828
    0.8660
         0
         0
```

Don't be alarmed with the last two entries having a standard deviation of 0.  That's the definition when you only have a data set that consists of 1 point.  There is only one point defined for both `x = 3` and `x = 4`.

Comment: Thanks! Consider a case where x is unsorted for e.g. 1 2 3 2 4 2 1. How will you obtain the corresponding x array.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia - That's easy.  Let me modify my answer.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia - Done.  Check my edits.  I would use my answer with `accumarray` to make this more flexible.